# How do I determine why the getters and setters of POJOs generated from an AVSC file are not present?

Tags: java, maven, avro

I am using the Maven Avro plugin to generate POJOs from an AVSC file. Unfortunately, the top-most class that is generated from this file - loanInitiate - does not appear to contain any of the getters and setters needed for the other structures within the schema.

The POJOs that are generated for the child nodes do have the expected getters and setters. For example, the Customer class is generated and has a `getNameBase()` method.

I have tried editing this file in a variety of ways - changing structure, etc. - but I keep running into situations where the format is not valid.

Why would some of the getters and setters be generated and not others?

The Avro schema file is defined as follows:

```
{
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "loanInitiate",
        "type": [
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "eventheader",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "eventType",
                        "type": "string",
                        "doc": "Loan"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventSubtype",
                        "type": "string",
                        "doc": "Initiate"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventDateTime",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventGeneratedDateTime",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventCorrelationId",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventRequestId",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventSourceDescription",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventSource",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ],
                        "doc": "The producer of this message."
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventInitiator",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventBatchGroupId",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ],
                        "doc": "BatchGroupID represents the GUID value given to each individual message which is part of a single batch."
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eventBatchRecordCountTotal",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ],
                        "doc": "BatchRecordCountTotal  provides the total number of messages belonging to a single batch."
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "array",
                "name": "customer",
                "items": {
                    "name": "customer",
                    "type": "record",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "nameBase",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "record",
                                "name": "nameBase",
                                "fields": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "givenName",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "otherGivenName",
                                        "type": [
                                            "string",
                                            "null"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "fullName",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "suffix",
                                        "type": [
                                            "string",
                                            "null"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "surname",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "titlePrefix",
                                        "type": [
                                            "string",
                                            "null"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "party",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "record",
                                "name": "party",
                                "fields": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "parentEntityId",
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "doc": "The value of this field should equal the value the id field of the parent object."
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "partyRole",
                                        "type": {
                                            "type": "record",
                                            "name": "partyRole",
                                            "fields": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "code",
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "name": "code",
                                                        "type": "enum",
                                                        "symbols": [
                                                            "INSD",
                                                            "OWNR",
                                                            "PPAY",
                                                            "RCP"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "subCode",
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "name": "subCode",
                                                        "type": "enum",
                                                        "symbols": [
                                                            "PRMR",
                                                            "LIST",
                                                            "BEN",
                                                            "DRBR",
                                                            "JNT"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "id",
                            "type": "string",
                            "doc": "This is the identifier for an instance of customer, which can be related to from other objects."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "bankAccount",
                "type": "record",
                "doc": "This object represents the bank account information, required for loan disbursements via ACH.",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "accountType",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "accountType",
                            "type": "enum",
                            "symbols": [
                                "CHKNG",
                                "SVNG"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "fullName",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "bankName",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "accountNumber",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "routingNumber",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "trackingeventdetails",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "workEventIdent",
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ],
                        "doc": "This field will be populated based on the creation of a tracking work event.  This field value holds the key for that particular event."
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "applicationId",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "divisionCode",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "departmentCode",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "workEventNumber",
                        "type": "int"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "longComment",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "actualEventDate",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "priorityCode",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "contactTypeCode",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "receivedDate",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "shortComment",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "lastUpdatedBy",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "loggedByIdent",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "resourceId",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "requestOrTypeCode",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "serviceChannelSourceCode",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "nigoCode",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "imageAvailableIndicator",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "completionIndicator",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "policy",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "type": "int"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "number",
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "agreementNumberPrefix",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "agreementNumberSuffix",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "adminSystem",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "loantransactiondetails",
                "doc": "This represents the values specific to the loan transaction.",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "transactionAmount",
                        "type": "string",
                        "doc": "The amount of the loan."
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "transactionType",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "transferAmount",
                        "type": {
                            "name": "transferAmount",
                            "type": "enum",
                            "symbols": [
                                "Max",
                                "Other"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"type": "record",
"namespace": "com.stream.process",
"name": "loanInitiate"
}
```

Comment: Unrelated - Since each record is a Java class, they should start with capital letters

Comment: Agreed - this schema came out of some enterprise-wide initiative that leverages ACORD, which defined them this way.